# Выполнение операций у свернутого приложения

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

Добрый день, такая задача - нужно выполнять периодические запросы на сервер раз в какой-то промежуток времени, при этом, приложение может быть свернуто, каким способом это лучше реализовать? Можно ли это реализовать вообще? Знаю, что у Android это можно реализовать с помощью `alarmManager`

Comment: в ios7 и выше есть такая штука background fetch. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Оформите ответ, в итоге он оказался верным для моего кейса